# Sequelize, apply transaction to other nested transactions

Tags: node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

I don't know whether the topic describe correctly what I'm writing here.
I have an idea:

I have:

```
db.transaction(async t => {
  await Period.bulkCreate(newPeriods);

   const currentPeriods = await Period.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'firstDay', 'lastDay'],
      where: { termId: id }
    });

  const updatedDate = {
          id: dates[j].id,
          periodId: currentPeriods[i].dataValues.id
          date: dates[j].dataValues.date
        };
  await Date.update(
    updatedDate,
    { where: { period: existedPeriods[i].id } },
    { transaction: t }
  );
})
```

Currently, everything is oke. But I want to put the bulkCreate into a transaction like this:

```
  await GradingPeriod.bulkCreate(newPeriods, { transaction: t });
```

And the **currentPeriods** will be an empty array. Is there anyway to use a transaction to wrap it? Maybe something like this

```
db.transaction(async t => {
  db.transaction(async t1 => {
  // some other work with Period
    await Period.bulkCreate(newPeriods, {transaction: t, transaction: t1});
  }).then().catch();


   const currentPeriods = await Period.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'firstDay', 'lastDay'],
      where: { termId: id }
    });

  db.transaction(async t2 => {
  const updatedDate = {
              id: dates[j].id,
              periodId: currentPeriods[i].dataValues.id
              date: dates[j].dataValues.date
            };
      await Date.update(
        updatedDate,
        { where: { period: existedPeriods[i].id } },
        { transaction: t, transaction: t2 }
      );
  }).then().catch();
}).then().catch();
```

So whenever the transaction t1 or t2 is rollback, so the whole transaction t will be rollback too.I did many researchs but it seem I still not search with correct keyword. So please help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want them to wrap in one transaction?

Comment: I tried, as I described above, I want to use currentPeriods after do crud, everything work well with update query, but not the bulkCreate

Answer (score 0):

Here on line 2

```
 db.transaction(async t1 => {...
```

use parent transaction on options param like:

```
 db.transaction({transaction: t}, async t1 => {...
```

As in the [source code for transactions](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/56bb1d6ef9827f604d7bcef945abb7e213f2322d/lib/transaction.js#L36-L47)

Can use it too in the t2 `db.transaction(async t2 => {`.